# Integration details

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

How to do this integral details?
 \begin{equation*}
\int_0^\infty a_0 \sqrt{r} e^{-r^2/R^2}  J_\frac{1}{2}(kr)r \, \mathrm{d}r.
\end{equation*}

It can be done easily by Mathematica:

```
Integrate[ a0*Sqrt[r]*Exp[-r^2/R^2]*BesselJ[1/2, r k]*r, {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

then

```
"Simplify[%,R>0]"
```

The result is: $a_0 \frac{k R^3 e^{-\frac{1}{4} k^2 R^2}}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}$

Comment: Your latex formula has a $k$ in the end, while your mathematica formula has a $r$: which one is the right one?

Comment: I think this will not make any difference.]

Comment: It makes a difference @ComplexGuy

Comment: Can you check this answer please. The final result is analogous with my expectation. So how did it affect? Can you please explain?

Comment: The integral over $k$ doesn't converge for starters.

Comment: The output you are showing from Mathematica is incorrect.  I derived, and Mathematica confirmed, the following result:$$\frac{a_0 \sqrt{k} R^3 e^{-\frac{1}{4} k^2 R^2}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: what was the wrong?

Comment: See my answer below.  There should be no $\sqrt{\pi}$ in the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to evaluate the following integral in a non-obvious way:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dr \, r \, \sin{k r} \, e^{-r^2/R^2}$$

Note that

$$J_{1/2}(k r) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k r}} \sin{k r}$$

so that we are really interested in the above integral.  The factor in the square root will be put in for the final step.

Now, the obvious way to evaluate the above integral is to consider the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dr \, \cos{k r} \, e^{-r^2/R^2}$$

and then take the derivative with respect to $k$.  This is indeed a correct way to go...but wholly uninteresting to me and so thoroughly repeated throughout this site to be a bore.  I am going to illustrate a less well-known method that deserves notice here: Cauchy's theorem.

We begin by considering the following integral in the complex plane:

$$\oint_C dz \, z \, e^{-z^2/R^2}$$

where $C$ is a rectangular contour having vertices $-i a$, $N-i a$, $N+i a$, and $i a$, such that $a \gt 0$.  By Cauchy's theorem, this integral is zero.  This means that, writing out the integrals around the contour, we have

$$\int_0^N dx\,(x-i a) \, e^{-(x-i a)^2/R^2} + i \int_{-a}^a dy \,(N+i y) \, e^{-(N+i y)^2/R^2} + \\ \int_N^0 dx (x+i a) \, e^{-(x+i a)^2/R^2} + i \int_{a}^{-a} dy \,(i y) \, e^{-(i y)^2/R^2} = 0$$

We seek the limit as $N\to \infty$.  In this limit, the second integral vanishes.  Note also that the fourth integral vanishes, as it is an integral of an odd function over an even interval.  Rearranging the other two integrals, we get

$$e^{a^2/R^2} \int_0^{\infty} dx \, x\, e^{-x^2/R^2} \left (e^{i 2 a x/R^2} - e^{-i 2 a x/R^2} \right ) - i a e^{a^2/R^2} \int_0^{\infty} dx \,e^{-x^2/R^2} \left (e^{i 2 a x/R^2} + e^{-i 2 a x/R^2} \right )=0$$

or

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, x\, e^{-x^2/R^2}\, \sin{\frac{2 a x}{R^2}} = a \int_0^{\infty} dx \,  e^{-x^2/R^2}\, \cos{\frac{2 a x}{R^2}}$$

Now plug in $a=k R^2/2$, and you get the same result from differentiating the cosine integral above.  This cosine integral is done directly far more easily than the original sine integral (which drove me to consider the contour integration method above):

$$\int_0^{\infty} dr \, \cos{k r} \, e^{-r^2/R^2} = \frac12 \text{Re} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dr \, e^{i k r} \, e^{-r^2/R^2}= \frac12 e^{-R^2 k^2/4} \text{Re} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dr \, e^{-(x-i k R^2/2)^2/R^2}$$

Therefore

$$\int_0^{\infty} dr \, r \, \sin{k r} \, e^{-r^2/R^2} = \frac{k R^2}{2} e^{-R^2 k^2/4} \frac12 \sqrt{\pi} R $$

Now multiply by the factor $\sqrt{2/(\pi k)}$ to get the value of the sought-after integral:

$$\frac{a_0 \sqrt{k} R^3 e^{-\frac{1}{4} k^2 R^2}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479876/inverse-fourier-transform-to-find-out-hat-c-1 can you please check the same question in this link

Comment: It seems i have done a mistakes because the integration  I attached the link is done after doing the inverse transformation, so the integration was done wrt r. but in this question it is done wrt k.?

Comment: @ComplexGuy: no offense, but are you reading my solution closely enough?  I think you ask so many questions because you either simply are failing to do so, or the material is a bit too difficult.

Comment: @ComplexGuy: no, it has nothing to do with that.  I am not sure why that answer returned the $\sqrt{\pi}$, but it is incorrect.

Comment: I understand my petty mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
?
&=
\int_{0}^{\infty}a_{0}\,\sqrt{r\,}\,{\rm e}^{-r{^2}/R^{2}}\
\overbrace{\quad{\rm J}_{\rm 1/2}\left(kr\right)\quad}
^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\LARGE A}2\ \over \pi kr\,}\,\sin\left(kr\right)}r\,{\rm d}r
=
a_{0}\,\sqrt{2 \over \pi k\,}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-r^{2}/R^{2}}
\sin\left(kr\right)r\,{\rm d}r
\\[3mm]&=
{a_{0}R^{2} \over \sqrt{2\pi k\,}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-r^{2}}
\sin\left(kR\,r\right)r\,{\rm d}r
=
{a_{0}R^{2} \over \sqrt{2\pi k\,}}\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\rm e}^{-\left(r^{2} - {\rm i}kR\,r\right)}r\,{\rm d}r
\\[3mm]&=
{a_{0}R^{2} \over \sqrt{2\pi k\,}}\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\rm e}^{-\left\lbrack\left(r - {\rm i}kR/2\right)^{2} + k^{2}R^{2}/4\right\rbrack}
\,r\,{\rm d}r
=
{a_{0}R^{2} \over \sqrt{2\pi k\,}}{\rm e}^{-k^{2}R^{2}/4}
\,\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\rm e}^{-\left(r - {\rm i}kR/2\right)^{2}}
\,r\,{\rm d}r
\\[3mm]&=
{a_{0}R^{2} \over \sqrt{2\pi k\,}}{\rm e}^{-k^{2}R^{2}/4}
\,\Im\int_{-\infty - {\rm i}kR/2}^{\infty - {\rm i}kR/2}{\rm e}^{-r^{2}}
\,\left(r + {1 \over 2}\,{\rm i}kR\right)\,{\rm d}r
\\[3mm]&=
{a_{0}R^{2} \over \sqrt{2\pi k\,}}{\rm e}^{-k^{2}R^{2}/4}
\,\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-r^{2}}
\,\left(r + {1 \over 2}\,{\rm i}kR\right)\,{\rm d}r
=
{a_{0}R^{2} \over \sqrt{2\pi k\,}}{\rm e}^{-k^{2}R^{2}/4}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-r^{2}}
\left({1 \over 2}\,kR\right)\,{\rm d}r
\\[3mm]&=
{a_{0}R^{2} \over \sqrt{2\pi k\,}}{\rm e}^{-k^{2}R^{2}/4}
\left({1 \over 2}\,kR\right)
\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-r^{2}}}^{\sqrt{\pi\,}}
\,{\rm d}r
\end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
?
=
2\,\sqrt{2 \over \pi\,}\,a_{0}\,k^{-5/2}\left(kR \over 2\right)^{3}
{\rm e}^{-\left(kR/2\right)^{2}}\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$